# API request getting stuck in POSTMAN?

Tags: regex, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

So, I am making an e-shop app which uses Mongo DB and Express JS as the backend. I have already created the productSchema, userSchema and the categorySchema and have coded for the appropriate GET requests.

I have made a jwt.js file which handles whether the the GET request should be allowed or not based on the token.

The code for jwt.js is given below

```
const { expressjwt } = require("express-jwt");

function authJwt() {
  const secret = process.env.secret;
  const api = process.env.API_URL;
  return expressjwt({
    secret,
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
    isRevoked: isRevoked,
  }).unless({
    path: [
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/products(.*)/, methods: ["GET", "OPTIONS"] },
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/categories(.*)/, methods: ["GET", "OPTIONS"] },
      `${api}/users/login`,
      `${api}/users/register`,
    ],
  });
}

async function isRevoked(req, payload, done) {
  if (!payload.isAdmin) {
    done(null, true);
  }

  done();
}

module.exports = authJwt;
```

The code for products.js which handles the GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests for the products database is given below.

```
const { Product } = require("../models/product");
const express = require("express");
const { Category } = require("../models/category");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

router.get(`/`, async (req, res) => {
  // localhost:3000/api/v1/products?categories=2342342,234234
  let filter = {};
  if (req.query.categories) {
    filter = { category: req.query.categories.split(",") };
  }

  const productList = await Product.find(filter).populate("category");

  if (!productList) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  }
  res.send(productList);
});

router.get(`/:id`, async (req, res) => {
  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).populate("category");

  if (!product) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  }
  res.send(product);
});

router.post(`/`, async (req, res) => {
  const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
  if (!category) return res.status(400).send("Invalid Category");

  let product = new Product({
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
    image: req.body.image,
    brand: req.body.brand,
    price: req.body.price,
    category: req.body.category,
    countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
    rating: req.body.rating,
    numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
    isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
  });

  product = await product.save();

  if (!product) return res.status(500).send("The product cannot be created");

  res.send(product);
});

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  if (!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)) {
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid Product Id");
  }
  const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
  if (!category) return res.status(400).send("Invalid Category");

  const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      name: req.body.name,
      description: req.body.description,
      richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
      image: req.body.image,
      brand: req.body.brand,
      price: req.body.price,
      category: req.body.category,
      countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
      rating: req.body.rating,
      numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
      isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  if (!product) return res.status(500).send("the product cannot be updated!");

  res.send(product);
});

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Product.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((product) => {
      if (product) {
        return res
          .status(200)
          .json({ success: true, message: "the product is deleted!" });
      } else {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({ success: false, message: "product not found!" });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: err });
    });
});

router.get(`/get/count`, async (req, res) => {
  const productCount = await Product.countDocuments((count) => count);

  if (!productCount) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  }
  res.send({
    productCount: productCount,
  });
});

router.get(`/get/featured/:count`, async (req, res) => {
  const count = req.params.count ? req.params.count : 0;
  const products = await Product.find({ isFeatured: true }).limit(+count);

  if (!products) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  }
  res.send(products);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now, the codes for the users.js and categories.js are similar and thus I am not sharing it.

I am getting the problem when doing GET request for products using POSTMAN API. Even though I am passing the correct token using BEARER TOKEN field in the POSTMAN API, it is getting stuck at sending request. When I delete the isRevoked part, everything works fine, but then again I can't control the get request based on the isAdmin part. So, the problem is in the isRevoked part. But, what exactly is the issue. It seems fine to me logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem could arise from so many things, could not say without a deeper look at your code but, here are some suggestions:

1. should isRevoked be async?
2. does your payload contains isAdmin?
   and if so, inside the if statement should be `done(null, false)` after the if statement you should get a userid or any sort of unique fields such as userEmail, ..., then use your userModel to query the user document so that your last `done()` be `done(null, user)`

Comment: My payload does contain isAdmin. I will check with the logic you have given me and test it out.

Comment: So after the if statement, my code should look like-
`const user = await User.find()
done(null, user)
`

Comment: yes exactly you have to pass the user document as the second argument to the `done()` so that later you can access it via `req.user`